# SQL Server view when trying to use the same columns multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table named 'computers' with the following cols:
row_id
computer_id
key
value

The value for a row where key equals '3' contains the name of the computer.
The value for a row where key equals '4' contains the IP of the computer.
The value for a row where key equals '5' contains the user of the computer.

Computer_id represents a specific unique computer.

I would like to create a view that would have the following cols:
computer_id
name
ip_address
user

I am struggling with how to do this. I am sure it cannot be that complicated but having difficulty trying to reference the same columns (key, value) multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the computer id, and pick the right keys using max and case.  For example:

```
select  computer_id
,       max(case when key = 3 then value end) as Name
,       max(case when key = 4 then value end) as IP
,       max(case when key = 5 then value end) as User
from    YourTable
group by
        computer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW your_view
AS
SELECT x.computer_id, x.value AS name, y.value AS ip_address, z.value AS user
FROM computers AS x
    INNER JOIN computers AS y
        ON x.computer_id = y.computer_id
    INNER JOIN computers AS z
        ON x.computer_id = z.computer_id
WHERE x.key = 3
    AND y.key = 4
    AND z.key = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is to subqueries:

```
SELECT
    computer_id,
    value AS 'name',
    (SELECT value FROM computers sqi WHERE sqi.computer_id = computers.computer_id AND sqi.key = 4) AS 'ip',
    (SELECT value FROM computers squ WHERE squ.computer_id = computers.computer_id AND squ.key = 5) AS 'user'
FROM
   computers
WHERE
   key = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  computer_id, 
max(case when [KEY] = 3 then value end) as Name, 
max(case when [KEY] = 4 then value end) as IP, 
max(case when [KEY] = 5 then value end) as [User]
from  YourTable
group by computer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're querying is a table that follows the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) design. Here's an [article with some examples](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/28569263/querying-an-eav-table.aspx) of how EAVs can/need to be queried.

Here's a subquery sample for your table definition:

```
SELECT x.Computer_Id,
(SELECT value FROM Computers AS a WHERE x.Computer_Id = a.Computer_Id AND [key]= 3) AS 'Name',
(SELECT value FROM Computers AS b WHERE x.Computer_Id = b.Computer_Id AND [key]= 4) AS 'IpAddress',
(SELECT value FROM Computers AS c WHERE x.Computer_Id = c.Computer_Id AND [key]= 5) AS 'User'
FROM Computers as x
GROUP BY x.Computer_Id
```